# Angular UI Bootstrap time picker - chevron icon missing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker, angularjs-ng-template

Hi I have been using Angular ui bootstrap time picker and its working fine. But, the up and down arrow - chevron icons are missing. Its seen as shown in the screenshot. I inspeacted element and changed "icon-chevron-down" to "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" and its working fine.

But, as I am using bower and dynamic html ("bootstrap-timepicker": "~0.3.0", and "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "~1.2.1"), I am not sure how can I edit this and update glyphicon class?

[image]

I am sure, I need to create a custom template to override the following in my html:

```css
From bootstrap-timepicker.js:

templateContent = '<table>'+
         '<tr>'+
           '<td><a href="#" data-action="incrementHour"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a></td>'+

...
```

But, I am not sure what id I should be using to create my template?

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?